# SQL: INSERT multiple different hardcoded values in one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, sql-insert

I could not find a solution for this yet. I want to insert multiple rows with 2 or more different hardcoded values, but also with data that I get from another table.

Example: I want to add 2 items into a table for a user that has the ID = '0' in another table without running 2 queries.

This is what I've done so far:

```
INSERT INTO
  DB.dbo.Table WITH(ROWLOCK, XLOCK) (
    col1,
    col2,
    col3,
    col4
  )
SELECT
  DISTINCT customer_id,
    hardcoded_value1,
    constant1,
    constant2
FROM
  DB.dbo.Other_Table
WHERE
  ID = '0';
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: you see "hardcoded_value1" and I want to have not only 1 per query, but multiple hardcoded values for col2 without running the queries multiple times for each hardcoded value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `cross join` your `select` query with a table value constructor that holds several records with harcoded values. This will generate as many rows as provided in the table value constructor for each row return by the query.

```
INSERT INTO
  DB.dbo.Table WITH(ROWLOCK, XLOCK) (
    col1,
    col2,
    col3,
    col4
  )
SELECT
  DISTINCT t.customer_id,
    x.hardcoded_value,
    t.constant1,
    t.onstant2
FROM DB.dbo.Other_Table t
CROSS JOIN (VALUES ('harcoded 1'), ('harcoded 2')) as x(hardcoded_value)
WHERE t.ID = '0';
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this seems to be the thing that I needed. :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell from your question what the basis is for the different values.  You may be able to use a `CASE` statement to insert different hardcoded values based on some criteria:

```
INSERT INTO
  DB.dbo.Table WITH(ROWLOCK, XLOCK) (
    col1,
    col2,
    col3,
    col4
  )
SELECT
  DISTINCT customer_id,
    CASE WHEN Condition1 THEN hardcoded_value1
         WHEN Condition2 THEN hardcoded_value2
         ...
    END,
    constant1,
    constant2
FROM
  DB.dbo.Other_Table
WHERE
  ID = '0';
```